# Can an HTML5 localStorage key be any string?

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser, local-storage

I'm working on an application that will use HTML5 localStorage. I can't find anywhere whether there are any restrictions on the key besides the fact that it must be a string.

Specifically I'd like to know if I can use a URL as a key in localStorage across all browsers that support localStorage (eg, are symbols like `:/?#._-=+@!$%^&*()[]{}|<>` allowed to be used in the key?).

Also: what about whitespace? Is that allowed in a localStorage key across browsers?

I found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170716/are-there-any-characters-that-are-not-allowed-in-localstorage) but it only appears to have tested acceptable strings in localStorage values (not keys).

Comment: Couldn't you test and see if it worked? As for if it's "legal", I'm not sure there.

Comment: The test unfortunately crashed my browser. Working on modifying it so it won't.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The specification requires keys and values to be set and returned as a `DOMString` type value. DOMString is described in [DOM Level 3 Core][1] as:

```
A DOMString is a sequence of 16-bit units.

IDL Definition

    valuetype DOMString sequence<unsigned short>;
```

> The UTF-16 encoding was chosen because of its widespread industry
>   practice. Note that for both HTML and XML, the document character set
>   (and therefore the notation of numeric character references) is based
>   on UCS [ISO/IEC 10646]. A single numeric character reference in a
>   source document may therefore in some cases correspond to two 16-bit
>   units in a DOMString (a high surrogate and a low surrogate). For
>   issues related to string comparisons, refer to String Comparisons in
>   the DOM.
>
> For Java and ECMAScript, DOMString is bound to the String type because
>   both languages also use UTF-16 as their encoding.

So officially, any legal UTF-16 string is legal as a key or a value. Not every UTF-16 codepoint is a legal character though so you should try to avoid certain symbols like "surrogate pairs", "byte-order marks" and "reserved characters".

Answer (score 3):

I was able to adapt the test from the linked StackOverflow topic to test the keys as well:

```
function run_test(lowerlimit, UPPERLIMIT) {
    try {
        if (!window.localStorage) {
            // I recall that in one of the older Chrome version (4),
            // localStorage === null
            return 'Localstorage is not supported';
        }
        if (isNaN(lowerlimit) || isNaN(UPPERLIMIT) || lowerlimit > UPPERLIMIT) {
            return 'One of the limits is not a valid number!';
        }
        var i = lowerlimit - 1;
        var character_range = [];
        while (++i < UPPERLIMIT) character_range.push(i);
        input = String.fromCharCode.apply(String, character_range);
        localStorage.setItem(input, input);
        output = localStorage.getItem(input);
        if (input === output) {
            return true;
        }
        // Uh oh, not equal!
        var result = [];
        for (i=0; i<UPPERLIMIT-lowerlimit; i++) {
            if (input[i] !== output[i]) {
                result.push(i + lowerlimit);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }catch(e){return 'Error:' + e;}
}
run_test(0x20, 0xD7FF);
```

The result appears to be the same, at least in Chrome. Still need to test in other browsers.

Answer (score 2):

A simple test for browser support and key validity could be:

```
var testKey = "test";
var value = "some value";

if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined") {
  console.log("localStorage and sessionStorage support!");
  console.log("About to save. Local storage is:");
  console.log(localStorage);
  localStorage[testKey] = value;
  console.log("Key saved: "+ testKey);
  console.log(localStorage);
  localStorage.removeItem(testKey);  //<--- key deleted here
  console.log("key deleted: " + testKey);
  console.log(localStorage);
  console.log("DONE ===");
} else {
  console.log("Sorry! No web storage support..");
}
```

I´ve tested in Chrome running from console.

Adapted from http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can encode that string.

but Html storage has size limit.