# Image in localstorage function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, local-storage, filereader

I'm wrting a function which takes an image from a file input from a form and enables me to put it in localstorage. The function I wrote to achieve this:

```
function getImage() {
    var pic = document.getElementById("image").files[0];
    var imgUrl;
    var reader = new FileReader();  
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      var imgURL = reader.result;
      saveDataToLocalStorage(imgURL);
      return imgUrl;
    }
}
```

Then in another function I call this function and create a JSON entry in which I store values from other form inputs including the image. It looks like this:

```
    var imgUrl = getImage();

    // Create new JSON entry
    var json_entry = {'title': titleField.val(),
                        'image': imgUrl,
                        'content': contentField.val(),
                        'location': location};
```

Sadly the value of `imgUrl` is undefined.. There are no console errors. What am I doing wrong? And how can I fix this?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to store binary data in localStorage, which doesn't support binary data ?

Comment: Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: I don't know how to fix it. The code above is based on this example: http://jsfiddle.net/VXdkC/2/

Comment: @adeneo Chrome, Opera and Safari allow anything to be saved in localStorage: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11173673/938089 (IE and FF have some limitations though).

Answer (score 1):

I honestly don't know much about the `FileReader` object, but I can see just from glancing at your JS that (at least) one thing is off:

```
var imgUrl = getImage();
```

Your `getImage` function doesn't return anything; so `imgUrl` is definitely going to be `undefined` above.

If you want to do something with the `result` property of your `FileReader`, then you need to do so w/ a callback since you're handling the (asynchronous) `onload` event:

```
function getImage(callback) {
    // What are you doing with this?
    var pic = document.getElementById("image").files[0];

    var reader = new FileReader();  
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      var imgURL = reader.result;
      saveDataToLocalStorage(imgURL);

      // Note the difference here: rather than return from the event handler
      // (which effectively does nothing) we pass the result to a callback.
      callback(imgUrl);
    }

    // I assume you actually need to load something with the FileReader?
}
```

And then:

```
getImage(function(imgUrl) {
    var json_entry = {
        'title': titleField.val(),
        'image': imgUrl,
        'content': contentField.val(),
        'location': location
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are forgetting to set the reader to `readAsDataUrl`. Likely the value is coming back as `undefined` because `localStorage` does not inherently know how to serialize binary data. Setting the reader to `readAsDataUrl` changes `reader.result` onload.

```
var reader = new FileReader();  
reader.onload = function(e) {
  var imgURL = reader.result;
  saveDataToLocalStorage(imgURL);
  callback(imgUrl);
};
// add this line
reader.readAsDataURL(pic);
```

Have a look at [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) article, especially the section titled **Reading Files**. Note in the linked example the author uses `e.target.result` instead of `reader.result`. This *should* be the same value.